# CakePHP : How to Call chat plugin action by jQuery?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using this chat plugin:

http://sandbox2.pseudocoder.com/demo/chat

In chat.js, I tried using the below code for calling plugin action in plugin controller,

```
$.fn.chat.defaults = {
  update:'/{project_name}/{plugin_name}/{plugin_controller_name}/{plugin_controller_action}',
  interval: 50000
};

/*
$.fn.chat.defaults = {
    update: '/hasina/chat/Chat/update',
    interval: 50000
};

project_name: hasina,
plugin_name : chat,
plugin_controller_name : Chat,
plugin_controller_action : update
*/
```

How can i call plugin action by js ,which is in plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this plugin before. This is how I have it:

```
$.fn.chat.defaults = {
    update: '/web/chat/update',
    interval: 15000
};
```

My web application is under /web/. So try using:

```
$.fn.chat.defaults = {
    update: '/hasina/chat/update',
    interval: 15000
};
```

Hope it works!